# How to avoid multiple callback levels in Android with geofences

Tags: android, api, asynchronous, google-api, geofencing

I'm trying to create an Android application with geofence locations that are loaded from an external API. I use retrofit to make the aysnc calls. The problem is that both the `googleApiClient` and the external API call are async. So I don't know which one finishes first in order to start the geofences.

If I start the geofences in the `onConnected()` of the `googleApiClient`, I might not yet have the LatLng's from the API. But if I start the geofences from the callback of the API, the `googleApiClient` might not yet have been loaded.

What could I do to handle this problem instead of just doing the async API call in the `onConnected()` of the `googleApiClient`. I'm trying to avoid multiple callback levels. Here is my code that currently doesn't work because I think the results of the API are not there yet when the `startGeofences()` is called:

```
public class GeofenceHelper implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, ResultCallback<Status> {
    private List<Geofence> mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<>();
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

 public GeofenceHelper(Activity context){
        this.context = context;
        permissionsHelper = new PermissionsHelper(context, REQ_PERMISSION);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        geofencePointsRequest();
    }

private void startGeofences() {
        Log.i(TAG, "startGeofences()");
        if (!googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Not connected");
            return;
        }
        if (permissionsHelper.checkPermission())
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    googleApiClient,
                    getGeofencingRequest(),
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this);  // Result processed in onResult()
    }

private void geofencePointsRequest() {
    GeofenceAreasRequest response = new GeofenceAreasRequest();
    response.getAllAreas(new GeofenceAreasResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onAreasLoaded(List<Point> points, int code) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Responsecode: " + String.valueOf(code));
            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                        .setRequestId(points.get(i).getName())
                        .setCircularRegion(
                                points.get(i).getLatitude(),
                                points.get(i).getLongitude(),
                                points.get(i).getRadius())
                        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                                | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                        .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                        .build());
            }
        }
    });
}


private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getGeofencingRequest");
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

public void start(){
    googleApiClient.connect();
}
public void stop(){
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "google api connected");
    startGeofences();
    getLastKnownLocation();
}
}
```

Comment: Try to make retrofit aysnc calls onConnected() method and when you got response of your calls then call startGeofences().

Comment: could you elaborate? Because isn't that what I'm trying to avoid to do as explained in my original post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach

```
public class GeofenceHelper implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, ResultCallback<Status> {
private List<Geofence> mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<>();
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;


private List<Point> pointsList = null;

public GeofenceHelper(Activity context) {
    this.context = context;
    permissionsHelper = new PermissionsHelper(context, REQ_PERMISSION);

    // let both work in parallel
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    geofencePointsRequest();
}

private void startGeofences() {
    Log.i(TAG, "startGeofences()");
    if (!googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Not connected");
        return;
    }
    if (permissionsHelper.checkPermission())
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                googleApiClient,
                getGeofencingRequest(),
                getGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this);  // Result processed in onResult()
}

private void registerGeofences() {

    if (pointsList != null) {
        // populate data in list
        for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.size(); i++) {
            mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId(pointsList.get(i).getName())
                    .setCircularRegion(
                            pointsList.get(i).getLatitude(),
                            pointsList.get(i).getLongitude(),
                            pointsList.get(i).getRadius())
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                            | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                    .build());
        }

        // this will actually register geofences
        startGeofences();

    }
}

private void geofencePointsRequest() {
    GeofenceAreasRequest response = new GeofenceAreasRequest();
    response.getAllAreas(new GeofenceAreasResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onAreasLoaded(List<Point> points, int code) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Responsecode: " + String.valueOf(code));

            pointsList = points;

            registerGeofences();
        }
    });
}


private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getGeofencingRequest");
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

public void start() {
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

public void stop() {
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "google api connected");
    getLastKnownLocation();
    registerGeofences();
}
```

}